# Expressing the cantor function on $[0,1]$ as a function on $\text{Ternary}([0,1])$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

I would to link the [simple function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220431/14108) and [probabilistic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220762/14108) approach for the calculation of the Fourier transform of the Cantor function.

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the Cantor function.
In the simple function approach, at some point appears
$$
\hat f'(x) = \int e^{-ixt} df(t)
$$
where the integral is on $[0,1]$.
Write $t$ in base-$3$ with 
$$
t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty t_n 3^{-n}, t_n \in T_n=\{0,1,2\}.
$$
Define a measure $g_n$ on $T_n$ by $dg_n(0)=dg_n(2)=1/2$ and $dg_n(1)=0$.
Then, viewing $f$ as a [product measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221473/14108) on
$$
T=\otimes_n (T_n,\sigma(T_n),g_n)
$$
gives
$$
df(t)=\prod_n dg_n(t_n).
$$

This construction gives the correct result for $\hat f'(x)$.
But is the construction correct?

I find strange to work with $df$ and $dg_n$.
Usually measure are defined directly, not through the differential.
Also, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Properties) states that the cantor function has no discrete part, which seems to contradicts the construction (2nd paragraph, 2nd phrase in the Properties section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual (probabilistic) construction of the uniform distribution $\mu$ on the standard Cantor set $C$, one introduces a sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ of i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution on $\{0,2\}$, and one considers
$$
X=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}3^{-n}X_n.
$$
Then $X$ is uniformly distributed on $C$, hence the Fourier transform $\widehat\mu$ of the measure $\mu$ is the function defined by
$$
\widehat\mu(t)=\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{\mathrm itx}\mathrm d\mu(x)=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX}).
$$
(Different normalizations are used but the steps below can be easily adapted.)

Now, by definition of stochastic independence,
$$
\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX})=\prod_{n\geqslant1}\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm it3^{-n}X_n})=\prod_{n\geqslant1}\varphi(t/3^{n}),
$$
where $\varphi(t)=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX_1})$, that is,
$\varphi(t)=\frac12(1+\mathrm e^{2\mathrm it})$.
Finally,
$$
\widehat\mu(t)=\prod_{n\geqslant1}\frac{1+\mathrm e^{2\mathrm it/3^n}}2=\mathrm e^{\mathrm it/2}\cdot\prod_{n\geqslant1}\cos(t/3^n).
$$
**Nota:** Indeed, $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x$, as can be seen by including $\{x\}$ in smaller and smaller triadic intervals of length $3^{-n}$, whose measure is, by definition, either $2^{-n}$ or zero, for every $n\geqslant1$. Likewise, recall that $C$ has Lebesgue measure zero hence $\mu$ and the Lebesgue measure are mutually singular.